# How to build (OpenGL Engine Ogre) SDK on Mac ?

Tags: macos, opengl, ogre

I'm getting familiar with Ogre openGL engine on mac. I followed this steps to setup the SDK version 1.8.0 on mac

1. Go to http://www.ogre3d.org and click on Download.
2. Next click on Download a Prebuilt SDK.
3. Download the latest OSX SDK.
4. Double-click the .dmg to mount it
5. Drag & drop the OgreSDK folder wherever you like to install the SDK
6. Start up Xcode and load the `OgreSDK/Samples/Samples.xcodeproj` to build the samples

I have a problem in last step, when I opened the .xcodeproj file and tried to build the All_Build target, it gives this error:

```
make -f /Applications/OgreSDK/CMakeScripts/ReRunCMake.make
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/CMake 2.8-8.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in', needed by `CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache'.  Stop.
make: *** [/Applications/OgreSDK/CMakeFiles/ZERO_CHECK] Error 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

Comment: Having the same problem. OS X 10.8.5, XCODE 5.0.2. : /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here it is a guide](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/CMake+Quick+Start+Guide?tikiversion=Mac%20OS%20X) that can help you with this.

In a nutshell your problem is that you haven't configured the build yet, you can generate a `makefile` and configure your build with `cmake`, everything is described in the linked guide.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply .. I tried this but I found an error while opening the generated xcode project "project can't be opened as it failed to parse the project file" from the cmake GUI, i think that the generation step is very short and has some error but i can't know why .. can you please tell me where can i find the source code folder exactly ? as I think it's my problem

Comment: I reached to this error after fixing the first error

--------------------------------------------------
/Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:44 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:171 (test_big_endian)
---------------------------------------
any help ?